Starting new site on expired domain with tiny spam history
I am considering to start a new site on an expired domain which published spam 2 years ago.
I have to launch a site in the Balkans. Luckily I could buy the exact keyword domains for Serbia and Croatia and the .com. I wanna go with the .com as that would fit the best. I am afraid that a Serbian .rs domain would lead to smaller CTR rates from Croatians and vica versa.
I made a background check on the .com which has the following results:

7 backlinks, no casino or medical links. Ahref's domain rating is 0.1

the domain hosted a blog between 2014-2019 with relevant content to
the keyword (I would disawow them, don't want to restore their
content)

between 2020-2021 it hosted a site with content about fish aquariums
in Chinese (this scares me)

seems like the Chinese site didn't link spammed, but I don't
understant why they done the whole thing on an irrelevant domain name
without a solid backlink profile


no indexed page shown by Google for searching site:domain.com
What I want to do with the domain:

create a site which will provide value for users

publish original content by humans

no PBN and content spam


My problem here is the Chinese site which hosted irrelevant content and possibly was a form of some spam. I tried to find something relevant from Google and found this post about the 2024 spam update: https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2024/03/core-update-spam-policies#expired-domain
Based on this post I could use the domain as I want to provide value content to the visitors, but I wanna be 100% sure as the site and content will cost a lot of money and I don't want to launch the .com, realize it's trash and move everything to .rs or .hr .
My question is: should I forget the .com because the possible spam Chinese content or Google will be smart enough to see no shady tactics are there?

I'm not an expert here, but I am fairly confident that you will be able to clean up the reputation of the site.   Google realizes sites get hacked/redirected etc all the time and makes allowances for it.   My guess is that if you have a worldwide audience - long term the advantages of a .com will outweigh the disadvantages of the domains history.

Do you already own the domain?  If so, perhaps register it with Google Search Console and see if that flags up any penalties.  From what you say, I'd  assume you'll be fine (the expired domain abuse is presumably going to go after lapsed high PageRank sites only - I can't see why a spammer would buy a domain with only 7 backlinks), but only Google really know.
